php serialize/unserialize new lines chars count (\n vs \r\n)
I'm facing some issue about how the characters count is performed with serialize/unserialize.
I must save this array in the db as a serialized string and then unserialize it when needed.
array(
  'testVar' => "1st line
2nd line
3rd line"
)

The serialized string is:
a:1:{s:7:"testVar";s:28:"1st line
2nd line
3rd line";}

As you see it counts as two chars each newline like \r\n, instead of one \n.
If I set s:26 when php unserializes it, throws this error:
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 51 of 56 bytes

I noticed that the real chars count is performed differently, if:

I copy-paste it in the database
I use a web form
I use the phpmyadmin GUI
on different platforms

I also noticed that the above error occurs also with these steps:

in localhost, in the web form textarea I insert an array manually (e.g. the one above)
submit the form
the php script replace \r\n with \n then output the serialized string
that string now contains the correct count (in this case 26)
copy-paste it in the db of another platform (not in localhost, e.g. using phpmyadmin)
perform php unserialize in that another platform

Also, different online serialize websites give the different chars count.
I'm a bit confusing on how it must works...
I need to add serialized strings in the db manually and sometimes from a web form, so how can I know which count type to use accordingly to the platform/machine?
Ps. there are for sure others better alternatives for non-objects array, like json_encode and/or base64, but I'm forced to use serialize...
Thanks

"I also noticed that even if I replace \r\n with \n before serialize the string with php and then output it in a web form textarea, it save it with \n count, correctly, but when performing unserialize it throw the above error." - Can you post an example of what you mean? The serialization process should be working on the bytes in the strings themselves. If one platform uses \r\n and another uses \n, PHP shouldn't care as long as the byte count is correct.

Why would you add serialized strings manually? Are the serialized strings being passed in already serialized, or are you attempting to create them manually instead of using the serialize function?

@ChrisHaas I edited the question, I hope now is clearer, thanks

@aynber I need to add/edit them manually in many cases, for work. Usually I edit them by using an online serialize/unserialize tool than copy-paste it in the db

@rozsazoltan how does it can help? I add it manually in the db, so I don't need any sql injection check and/or escape

I can think of two possible things. 1) When you copy and paste, your machine might be interpreting the strings using platform-specific line endings. 2) Same as above, but this time your browser. My guess is the latter. Per the spec, line feeds go through a normalization process.

If you want to be safe when transporting these you might have to add a base64 ecncode/decode step into the process.

@ChrisHaas sure, but I can't, it's not all my code... I would prefer json_encode but others forced to use serialize...

@user2342558, I totally get it, but once you leave PHP you are at the mercy of other specifications. There's no bug in PHP serialization engine, it is how it is being transported. You could try following the posted spec for normalizing the string before serializing to see if you can fix it that way.

Try this
$result = array_map(function($item) {

$split = explode(PHP_EOL, $item); 

array_walk($split, function(&$splitItem) {

    $splitItem = trim($splitItem);

});

return implode(PHP_EOL, $split);  
}, $array);


echo serialize($result);


I tested the PHP_EOL in both localhost and the other platform and both are \n, so it cannot help, also because I need to do that crossplatforms (create it locally and add it to another platform)
